# Git pull request - conflict

Tags: github, conflict

I am working in  my local branch-1 and my colleague works on his local branch branch-2.

He already committed and pushed the branch to his origin/develop and created a Pull request to upstream/develop. So now it is waiting for review and approving the pull request by someone else.

The problem is, in my local branch I need to edit one same file, which my colleague worked on. So my branch and his branch will containe the same file with different code. If his branch would be already in upstream, then I could merge it to my branch and resolve the conflict locally without problems.

However now it is in Pull request status waiting for review and I don't have time to wait, I need to create also my Pull request.

How and when will the conflict be solved, as the file with conflict is in both pull requests now, will git recognize it now or? As those branches are not in upstream yet.

Comment: It depends on which of the two pull requests will be merged first. If your pull request is merged first, this will cause a merge conflict in the pull request of your colleague and he will need to resolve it before it can be merged. If his request is merged first, then you will need to resolve the conflict.

Comment: If you actually mean Github pull request, make sure to include `github` tag in the question. If you mean some other pull request workflow style, then it should be explained more or the answers may not match any specific case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whichever branch is merged first, the *other* PR will have a merge conflict that must be resolved. If yours is merged first, theirs will suddenly have to fix a conflict. If their PR is merged, yours will have a conflict.

The PR main page will show the conflict and won't allow it to be merged.

Comment: I see, so there will be no conflicts untill one of the branches is merged. The question is, if the colleague's branch will be merged first, do I need to go check my PR and then the conflict message will be already there and I can solve it, or the reviewer needs to review the PR and solve my conflict?

Comment: The message will be there. If you merge the upstream development branch into your own branch with `git merge upstream development` a message will pop up on your terminal saying there is a merge conflict. Fix the file, then add, commit, and push again and the message in the PR will clear up.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is the correct one, but I want to add another possible course of action.

If your two separate features need to follow (for whatever business/architecture related reasons) **merging order**, where branch-1/feature-1 **must** be before branch-2/feature-2 and also at the same time, you need to create a PR for your feature, then what you need to do is rebase your branch on top of your colleagues branch and create a PR that way.

Once branch-1 is merged, then rebase branch-2 onto the latest `upstream/develop`. This will force you to resolve conflicts and update the PR accordingly.

Comment: thank you, in our case the order doesn't matter, we just worked on the same file in the same time